# Why are the branchless and built-in functions slower in Python?

Tags: python, performance, built-in, branchless

I found 2 branchless functions that find the maximum of two numbers in python, and compared them to an if statement and the built-in max function. I thought the branchless or the built-in functions would be the fastest, but the fastest was the if-statement function by a large margin. Does anybody know why this is? Here are the functions:

If-statement (2.16 seconds for 25000 operations):

```
def max1(a, b):
    if a > b:
        return a
    return b
```

Built-in (4.69 seconds for 25000 operations):

```
def max2(a, b):
    return max(a, b)
```

Branchless 1 (4.12 seconds for 25000 operations):

```
def max3(a, b):
    return (a > b) * a + (a <= b) * b
```

Branchless 2 (5.34 seconds for 25000 operations):

```
def max4(a, b):
    diff = a - b
    return a - (diff & diff >> 31)
```

Comment: Why do you think the branchless version should be faster? It has to do more work. It does 2 comparisons, 2 multiplications, and an addition.

Comment: I thought that was the point of branchless programming. If it's slower, what's the point of slower, less-readable code?

Comment: `if a > b` is one python opcode, `max` is at least 3: resolve max, push variables, call. Not to mention it will still probably branch internally.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi There's a function wrapper for all of them, so it's needed for a consistent comparison.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I understand that. But he wants to compare the differences in the bodies of all the ways to do it. The wrapper call is a constant that all the solutions entail, and it's just part of the test harness.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi That's fine: you want the extra lookup so that *every* run includes a call to `max{1,2,3,4}`, regardless of what happens in the *body* of each function.

Comment: @chepner, Barmar I see what you mean now

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your expectations about branching vs. branchless code apply to low-level languages like assembly and C. Branchless code can be faster in low-level languages because it prevents slowdowns caused by branch prediction misses. (Note: this means branchless code *can* be faster, but it will not necessarily be.)

Python is a high-level language. Assuming you are using the CPython interpreter: for every bytecode instruction you execute, the interpreter has to branch on the kind of opcode, and typically many other things. For example, even the simple `<` operator requires a branch to check for the `<` opcode, another branch to check whether the object's class implements a `__lt__` method, more branches to check whether the right-hand-side value is of a valid type for the comparison to be performed, and probably several other branches. Even your so-called "branchless" code will in practice result in a lot of branching for these reasons.

Because Python is so high-level, each bytecode instruction is actually doing quite a lot of work compared to a single machine-code instruction. So the performance of simple code like this will mainly depend on how many bytecode instructions have to be interpreted:

- Your `max1` function has to do three loads of local variables, a comparison, a conditional jump and a return. That's six.
- Your `max2` function does two loads of local variables, one load of a global variable (referencing the built-in `max`), and also makes a function call; that requires passing arguments, and is relatively expensive compared to other bytecode instructions. On top of that, the built-in function itself has to do the same work as your own `max1` function, so no wonder `max2` is slower.
- Your `max3` function does six loads of local variables, two comparisons, two multiplications, one addition, and one return. That's twelve instructions, so we should expect it to take about twice as long as `max1`.
- Likewise `max4` does five loads of local variables, one store to a local variable, one load of a constant, two subtractions, one bitshift, one bitwise "and", and one return. That's twelve instructions again.

That said, note that if we compare your `max1` with the built-in function `max` directly, instead of your `max2` which has an extra function call, your `max1` function is still *a bit faster* than the built-in `max`. This is probably because the built-in `max` accepts a variable number of arguments, which may involve building a tuple of arguments, and the built-in `max` function also has a branch to check if it was called with a single iterable argument (e.g. `max([3, 1, 4, 2])`), and handle that case differently; your `max1` function doesn't do those things.

Answer (score 4):

Python code is not machine optimized. It is highly unlikely that you get any "branchless" code optimization in the interpreted code.

Branchless code is faster sometimes if it effectively do less work or the hardware is able to do better branch prediction because of it.

Function call has cost, so if the code inside the function is too trivial, the cost of the function call is relatively high.

There is a missing control case: just call the builtin max function in a loop and compare (as in max2 but without the function call overhead). It is probable that builtin max is implemented in C and it is already optimized for your hardware.