# How do I make my number to excel coordinate converter work without if statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a python program that recreates an image in excel by filling cells with different shades of red, green and blue. I have made this method to convert a number to a x coordinate in excel:

```
alph = [i for i in string.ascii_uppercase]
alph.insert(0,'')
def numToExcel(x):
  stri = ''
  row = x
  rdiv26 = row//26
  rdiv676 = row//676
  stri += alph[(rdiv676)-((rdiv676)//676)*676]
  stri += alph[(rdiv26)-((rdiv26)//26)*26]
  stri += alph[1+(row%26)] 
  return stri
```

I added an empty space at the beginning so the program prints, for example, B3 instead of AAB3. However this means it does not reach for the letter Z. If i do x // 27 the image comes out wavy and it does not fix the issue.

This is my entire program:

```
import string
import time
import math
import openpyxl
from PIL import Image
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Color, PatternFill, Font, Border


alph = [i for i in string.ascii_uppercase]
alph.insert(0,'')

def rgb_to_hex(r, g, b):
  return '%02x%02x%02x' % (r,g,b)

def numToExcel(x):
  stri = ''
  row = x
  rdiv26 = row//26
  rdiv676 = row//676
  stri += alph[(rdiv676)-((rdiv676)//676)*676]
  stri += alph[(rdiv26)-((rdiv26)//26)*26]
  stri += alph[1+(row%26)] 
  return stri


wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active


im = Image.open('input.jpg')
pix = im.load()
x,y=im.size

start_time = time.time() 
ct=0
for j in range(1,y-1):
  i = 0
  while i < 3*(x-1):
    #Debug shi:     print("["+"#"*math.floor(20*(ct/(x*3*y)))+"-"*(20-math.floor(20*ct/(x*3*y)))+"] " + str(math.floor(ct/(x*3*y)*100))+"% "+ str(ct) + "/" + str(x*y))
    #Debug Shi:     print("["+"#"*math.floor(20*(ct/(x*3*y)))+"-"*(20-math.floor(20*ct/(x*3*y)))+"] " + str(math.floor(ct/(x*3*y)*100))+"% "+ str(ct) + "/" + str(x*y*3) + " | (" + numToExcel(i) + "," + str(j) + ") -> (" + numToExcel(i+2) + "," + str(j) +") | " + str(pix[i/3,j][0])+','+str(pix[i/3,j][1])+','+str(pix[i/3,j][2]))
    ws[numToExcel(i)+str(j)].fill = PatternFill("solid", fgColor=rgb_to_hex(pix[i/3,j][0],0,0))
    ws[numToExcel(i+1)+str(j)].fill = PatternFill("solid", fgColor=rgb_to_hex(0,pix[i/3,j][1],0))
    ws[numToExcel(i+2)+str(j)].fill = PatternFill("solid", fgColor=rgb_to_hex(0,0,pix[i/3,j][2]))
    i += 3
    ct += 3


  #Progress Bar and stuff 
  print("\n"*100)
  print("["+"#"*math.floor(20*(ct/(x*3*y)))+"-"*(20-math.floor(20*ct/(x*3*y)))+"] " + str(math.floor(ct/(x*3*y)*100))+"% "+ str(ct) + "/" + str(x*y*3) + " | Row " + str(j))

wb.save("sample2.xlsx")
print("--- Complete! ---\n--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

And here is the output:

[image: Code Output]

Please ignore any shitty code/math lol. I do not want to use any if statements because I am scared it would slow down the program.

Comment: *"I do not want to use any if statements because I am scared it would slow down the program."* This isn't applicable in Python; see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72118249/12299000).

Comment: @kaya3 oh ok I didnt know that, thank you. i would still prefer to solve this problem logically instead of just adding if statements.